# Do not access image url in buckt s3 outside the application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

To render images I'm using direct from the S3 bucket. But access can be done from outside the Reactjs application.
How do I prevent these S3 URLs from being accessed from outside the application?

Incorrectly authenticated logins

Comment: You can add a policy to [restrict access to a specific HTTP referer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html).  This will prevent some "hot linking", but can't stop a user from just downloading the images.

Comment: the image comes from a node js api and is accessed by the react.js application. But if I access the url in the browser, I can

Comment: I want to block this access

Comment: Then, add a policy for a specific HTTP referer as I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to serve images from an Amazon S3 bucket, but you only want these images to be accessed if people are using your application.

You can do this as follows:

- Keep the images in S3 bucket as 'private' -- do not make the bucket public
- When your application refers to an object in S3, it should generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provide time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3

The pre-signed URL will provide temporary access to a private object stored in the S3 bucket. Your application can generate the pre-signed URL by using an Access Key and Secret Key from credentials that are permitted to access the object. Generating a pre-signed URL only takes a couple of lines of code and does not require an API call to AWS.